# How to auth the API with API key and API token storing in .env

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, btoa

I write a  nodejs program to call data form API, it is working if I hard code the API key and token.

Hard code the API key and token is working:

```
let username = "userid"; //--API_USERNAME
let token = "hfdhdfgfdhgs24" //API TOKEN;
let auth = btoa(`${username}:${token}`);
```

I store the key and token into .env file , however cannot get the data when calling the API.

It seems cannot read the value from the .env file, would anyone can help?

```
//.env file
API_USERNAME=userid


//.js code
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config();
`var myHeaders = new Headers();
let token = "hfdhdfgfdhgs24" //API TOKEN;

let auth = btoa(`${process.env.API_USERNAME}:${token}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.env` gives you access to *environment variables*, i.e. what is exposed to the currently running process.

On Unix-like OS, you can do for example:

```bash
export API_USERNAME=myUserName && node ./myScript.js
```

---

The `.env` file is not automatically read by Node. You can use [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) library to do so: it will look for such file, and inject it into `process.env` for you:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

let username = process.env.API_USERNAME
```

Comment: tried before already before , it not working 

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
console.log(`USER_KEY ${process.env.API_USERNAME}`); 

let username = process.env.API_USERNAME;

Comment: Your `.env` file must be at the root of your project, or you must specify its location in the [`path`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path) config. If tou need further help, please edit your question to show your file structure and how you call your script.